# Invoking command with custom environment variables

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, scripting, powershell-1.0

How do i do the equivalent of this bash style command invocation in powershell 1.0

```
output = `VAR1=value /path/someCommand`
```

In essence i need to manufacture a private & temporary $env:VAR1 for the purpose of invoking someCommand.

Comment: The mentioned command (with spaces around `=`) wouldn't work even in `bash`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to define output as an alias for that bit of code? Or you want to execute and store the output of that code into output?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a process environment variable in PowerShell like so:

```
$env:VAR1 = 'value'
```

Then invoke the command:

```
/path/someCommand
```

Then remove the process env var:

```
remove-item Env:\Var1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to store the output of that command in var1:

```
$var1 = $_ | /path/someCommand
```

Assuming you want an alias so `output` will run that code whenever called:

```
Set-Alias output "$var = /path/someCommand"
```